# Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework tests failing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a small application and 2 unit tests look for exceptions and so I have the attribute `[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]` on them.

When I run the tests individually everything is fine. 
If I run all, the 2 with the exception decorators will fail and the others succeed. If I run a group of tests where this 1 test that has the ExpectedException on it, that test will fail.

The tests are really small and below are the 2 that have the `ExpectedException` attribute.

```
        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        public void WrongArgCountExceptionThrown()
        {
            List<string> args = new List<string>
            {
                "-t",
                "table_name",
                "-d",
                "2016-06-30"
            };

            Program prg = new Program();
            prg.Run(args.ToArray(), new Data(logRepo.Object, queueRepo.Object));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        public void WrongArgFormatExceptionThrown()
        {
            List<string> args = new List<string>
            {
                "t",
                "table_name",
                "-d",
                "2016-06-30",
                "-i",
                "1"
            };

            Program prg = new Program();
            prg.Run(args.ToArray(), new Data(logRepo.Object, queueRepo.Object));
        }
```

Comment: You have a mutable state inside of Program which apparently is not thread-safe or is held in memory or is looking at the same data.  There isn't enough here in your question however to tell you what exactly is causing the problem.

Comment: So in Program I use the CommandLine package (https://commandline.codeplex.com/) and it's a singleton object to parse the command line args (CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options) I assume this would be it. How would one handle a situation like this for unit testing? I suppose I have to make the Parser object itself vs using the Default?

Comment: You'd need to properly tear down and recreate the singleton object per test.

Comment: That's brutal. One of the settings is another object that seems way more involved :(. Thanks. Great reason to stay away from singletons it seems.

Comment: Singletons are not known for their testability :)

Comment: If you do decide to keep the singleton and tear it down and recreate it for each test, you can do that in a subroutine with the `[TestInitialize]` attribute on it.  It will be run before every test.